# Ping size limit - FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ping, root, denial-of-service

In the man page for FreeBSD ping:

> ```
>  -s packetsize
>          Specify the number of data bytes to be sent.  The default is 56,
>          which translates into 64 ICMP data bytes when combined with the 8
>          bytes of ICMP header data.  Only the super-user may specify val-
>          ues more than default.  This option cannot be used with ping
>          sweeps.
> ```

Does anyone know how I can let non-superusers send pings larger then 56? Can I increase the default size, or somehow allow -s to be used by non-root users? I am aware of the security implications, that this could allow users to start a ping flood, so if I can restrict this to allowing only a single (shell-less) user, all the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using sudo, EX:

```
coryj  ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/ping
```

This should let user `coryj` run `/bin/ping` (*caveat: using any args he likes, not just `-s`*) without a password.

Note the security implications of this; see man pages for `sudo(8)` and `sudoers(5)`.

Comment: Accepted this, seems a little cleaner then modifying the source, though modifying the source affords a little more granular control. Both good solutions. Personally I've been convinced to rethink my original reasons for doing this and accomplish my goals a different way.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the source code and change the behavior. You can make the default size bigger, it's on line `98` of `ping.c` in `/usr/src/sbin/ping/`. Or you can disable this feature on line `446` by replacing the line with `if (0) {`. After you change it, run `make install`.

I have to wonder why you would need a normal user to send a large ICMP message.